# Vectorized functions in R's data.table

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

**Problem:** I try to add to the below data.table object a column in which for each row a list of weeks will be displayed. I.e. if START = "2020-01-01" and END = "2020-01-15" the week column shall consist of a list of respective weeks for this time interval (2020 W01, 2020 W02, 2020 W03). I want to keep the function that prepares the data separatly due to code structure. However, the current function results in an error.

**Question:** Is there a way to keep it that simple i.e. w/o referring in the function call `get_weeks` to the data.table object? How could a modified function look like? Cheers!

```
dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  START = c("2020-01-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-14"),
  END = c("2020-01-15", "2020-03-12", "2020-03-26")
)


get_weeks <- function(start_date, end_date){

  date_range <- c(start_date, end_date)
  date_range <- ymd(date_range)

  dt_range <- seq.Date(date_range[1], date_range[2], "day")

  dt_range_week <- list(unique(format(as.Date(dt_range), "%G W%V")))

  dt_range_week
}


dt[, weeks_for_filter_table := get_weeks("START", "END")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Map`/`mapply` :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, weeks_for_filter_table := mapply(get_weeks, START, END)]
dt

#   ID      START        END     weeks_for_filter_table
#1:  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-15 2020 W01,2020 W02,2020 W03
#2:  2 2020-03-01 2020-03-12 2020 W09,2020 W10,2020 W11
#3:  3 2020-03-14 2020-03-26 2020 W11,2020 W12,2020 W13
```

Comment: Thanks! one follow-up question, I tried to filter the object now, e.g. `dt["2020 W01" %in% weeks_for_filter_table]` which unfortunately failed. Do you have an idea how to proceed here? (Expected Outcome: Row 1)

Comment: @rkraft `weeks_for_filter_table` is a list column. You can not filter them directly with `%in%`. Probably you need `dt[, .SD[sapply(weeks_for_filter_table, function(x) any(x == "2020 W01"))]]`